# R: visualization of relationships based on names and labels only

Tags: r, visualization

I need suggestions on how to visualize the similarities for the table based on names and labels only. 
Pie works for me, but I need to show some kind of similarity: for example tree3 and tree10 share the same feature - here is the link. I need simple solution. The RCircos seems to do what I need, but I got lost in documentation and probably I need something more simple.
Thanks!

```
name    feature
3   feature1
10  feature1
10  feature2
3   feature2
6   feature2
7   feature2
8   feature2
3   feature3
6   feature3
1   feature3
2   feature3
2   feature3
6   feature3
10  feature3
2   feature4
3   feature4
3   feature4
10  feature4
4   feature5
5   feature5
9   feature5
10  feature5
```

Comment: RCircos is not a base function. If it exists in a package, you need to name the package. (There is no link.)

Comment: I found out that the circlize has an option chordDiagram that do the trick pretty well. But I am looking for better options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I started out thinking I could show you a neat visualization function named 'mosaic' in the 'vcd' package but it didn't work out so well. Here's why: The data yoyu provide is just too sparse for proper use of that plotting routine. Look at the output of table:

```
 require(vcd)  # "visualizing categorical data"
with( dat, table(name, feature) )
#------------
    feature
name feature1 feature2 feature3 feature4 feature5
  1         0        0        1        0        0
  2         0        0        2        1        0
  3         1        1        1        2        0
  4         0        0        0        0        1
  5         0        0        0        0        1
  6         0        1        2        0        0
  7         0        1        0        0        0
  8         0        1        0        0        0
  9         0        0        0        0        1
  10        1        1        1        1        1
```

That seems to me to be the best way to display that small amount of data. The large number of empty "cells" is an important aspect that needs to be appreciated, and hte few cells with multiple values can be seen immediately.

And now look at the plot. The upper labels are very misleading since the first name category is dominated by 100% of its single value being 'feature3'.

```
 png(); mosaic( with( dat, table(name, feature) ) ); dev.off()
```

[image]

And that keeps the naming labels for the other categories from lining up in any sensible manner. But if this were just a toy data sample and the actual date were more dense, the mosaic plot may be very helpful in displaying the relative associations and marginal proportions in the same figure. If you reverse the order of arguments to `table` you get the proportions of 'name'

[image]

A little bit better. But the same sparsity causes a lack of good association of labels with values. If this is actually coming from a tree based 
analysis, you should display the tree rather than abstracting the names of the features without their underlying structure.

Comment: I thought your answer was better. (You can checkmark your own answers.)

Comment: it wouldn't work well with HD data, my table is significantly larger.

Answer (score 4):

I found an interesting solution

```
dat <- read.table("dat.txt", header=T)
dat <- with(dat, table(name, feature))
library(circlize)
chordDiagram(as.matrix(dat), transparency = 0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Now I need to find a function to color names grey, while keeping the feature color intact..